# a chain of terminal commands, each ran if a file exists

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

I looked for this in other questions but can't seem to find anything similar. Yet, this seems quite useful thing.

I want to set up a ZSH snippet/alias for my `git add .` so that it does three jobs in a chain:

1. if path `./readme.md` exists, run [doctoc](https://github.com/thlorenz/doctoc) (globally installed CLI app from npm) on it. **If it doesn't**, do nothing and skip to next step.
2. if path `./changelog.md` exists, run a different local CLI installed script on it (let's say called `changelogupd`). **If it doesn't**, do nothing and skip to next step.
3. no matter the previous outcomes, then run `git add .`

Now currently, I have **two** commands chained in `.zshrc` alias like this and it works:

```
path-exists ./readme.md && doctoc readme.md && git add . || git add .
```

But I want **three**: two path checks and conditional calls plus `git add .`

---

By the way. the `path-exists` is [path-exists-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-exists-cli), globally installed via npm.

Three command chain seems tricky, below is a nonsensical mash to show the rough thing I'm looking for:

```
path-exists ./readme.md && doctoc readme.md && git add . || path-exists ./changelog.md && changelogupd changelog.md && git add . || git add .
```

Should I try to cover all four cases using double pipes:

(

1. `readme` present, no `changelog`, plus `git add .`
2. `readme` not present, no `changelog`, plus `git add .`
3. both `readme` and `changelog` present, plus `git add .`
4. no `readme` but `changelog` present, plus `git add .`

)

or is there an easier way (or an npm CLI library or some secret terminal command)?

This is to be ran on a Mac terminal by the way. Thank you.

Comment: The idea of `A || B` is to run `B` only if `A` fails, which doesn't seem to be what you're looking for here, so any construction using `||` will be messy. Unless you have a really good reason to not do so, just write separate commands (with a newline or semicolon in between)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a function:

```
my-git-add-.() {
  [ -e readme.md ] && doctoc readme.md
  [ -e changelog.md ] && changelogupd changelog.md
  git add .
}
```

Comment: super elegant solution, I didn't think about functions!

Answer (score 2):

```
path-exists ./readme.md    && { doctoc       readme.md;    :; } || \
path-exists ./changelog.md && { changelogupd changelog.md; :; }
git add .
```

You need to group the commands to achieve what you are wanting. The `:` statement has been added to supply a true ending when doctoc might fail.